# Some fields not shown value in Edit view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult userprofile(int? id)
{
    var user = db.Educationaltables.Find(id);
    return View(user);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult userprofile(Educationaltable e)
{
    db.Entry(e).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

[Some fields are shown and some are not ....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFrNA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4AWj.png)

Comment: What's you return to the view? You may need to special something like this `return View(e);`

Comment: Nothing Happened .

Comment: @QingGuo I am writing a return RedirectToAction("Index"); insetead return view

Comment: @Narmeen please include EducationalTables.cs and View file to the question for better understanding